# ELO Rating for players that do not learn

Tags: unbiased-estimator, elo

Lately there are some AI competitions online, where the bot has no capability to "learn/adapt" (ironically) over games. Thus, each uploaded version of a bot by a player is static.

On the website, the K-factor is kept the same. I'd consider changing the K-factor based on how many games both bots in a match up have played, would that be a good idea considering that the bots do not learn? The website experiences too much variation.

Comment: This is a statistical question, and not off-topic!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @wolfies Challenge: find the question mark.

Comment: Do you manage the website? Or have access to all the results? Maybe try differnet K-factors, and cross-validate them. Changing the K-factor dynamically don't make much sense to me, as that is mostly done as a reaction to learning